# Is this a common use of 取り置き?

Tags: translation, meaning

【大ニュース！】. . 8月6日(日)Lovesofa は Africaリリースパーティー. . みんなでお祝いしましょう！. . いつもと違うLovesofaが見れるかも？. . **取り置きお待ちしてます！**

I need some help with this Tweet.  I understand everything except the last sentence. I've Googled, and asked around among some (older) Japanese friends and everyone seems a little stumped. Based on the context, it occurred to me that rather than the dictionary definition of "layaway," perhaps it means "pre-order" instead? As, in "We await your pre-orders (of our latest album/CD)." Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

"Pre-order" is not too far, but "(ticket) reservation" might be a better word. It specifically refers to a certain system small Japanese ライブハウス use. When an event is not big enough to use a dedicated ticket agency, they use this 取り置き system to sell tickets.

Basically you can call or email the club and make your tickets "reserved". Sometimes the performer/organizer themselves will accept such reservation. On the day of the event, you come to the club, tell your name at the reception, and get your reserved paper ticket. So it's essentially similar to a reservation of a restaurant, but you cannot use 取り置き for reserving restaurants. You cannot use 取り置き for pre-ordering in general, either.

Comment: なるほど！ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2):

[From コトバンク](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%8F%96%E3%82%8A%E7%BD%AE%E3%81%8D-343996)

It seems you got the general idea correct, going by the first definition on the link.
Probably best translated something along the lines of "Get it/Pre-order before it's all gone!"

As for how common the phrase is, a quick search turns up almost exclusively with stores (as one might expect). So in that context, it's something you'll probably see from time to time, but I highly doubt it's a word you'll use often in daily life (At least I know I've never personally used the phrase). In most cases, I think 予約 is preferred, though I suppose that is for before an item goes on sale, while 取り置き can happen after.

Comment: If someone (or you) can, we should probably also answer their question as to whether this particular use is common.

Comment: Good call. I missed the title, and it wasn't in the question body. Then again, I don't have an answer......

Comment: Thanks. It seems to be common as a Twitter hashtag related to music events, so I'm guessing its common only within that realm.